# position absolute div and centered positioning of its elements

Tags: css, positioning, absolute

While editing the css theme of news boxes at this site: http://pureenergy.nazwa.pl/fwwm/wordpress/?page_id=364

I have encountered two problems, both of them I cannot resolve for a long time. I am hoping that by asking a question here, you will be able to help me with sloving these issues :).

Two bugs concern the `.category1` div and `.info .aut` element.

Firstly, when it comes to categories, I wish them to be centered and not to occupy the whole width of the box, but only the width which they have by default. The full width of the box, I can remove by deleting `width:100%` instruction from `.category1` div. But unfortunately, caregories still stick to the left, even though I remove the `float:left` instruction. I am also unable to make negative px/% margins because the width of the category is not fixed (generates itself on the basis of category name). What should I do to have the categories centered and not occupy the whole width of the box?

Secondly, I have similar issue in `.info .aut` element. I wish elements of this div to be centered, regardless of their width, generated automatically on the basis of autor's name. Now it is centered because it is given an artificial width of `180px`, and unfortunately it does not look good in all cases. What should I do to have this div elements centered properly?

I am looking forward to your help! Thanks in advance :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `floats` from the elements which you want to be centered and add `display: inline-block; width: auto;` also add `text-align: center;` to parent element.